# Testing Spring Boot Security simply

Tags: java, spring, security, testing, spring-boot

I'm struggling with testing access control on URLs protected by Spring Security.

The configuration looks like this:

```
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/user/**", "/user").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**", "/templates/admin/**", "/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
```

And the test class looks like this:

```
package com.kubukoz.myapp;

import com.kubukoz.myapp.config.WebSecurityConfig;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MyApplication.class, WebSecurityConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
public class MyApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                .dispatchOptions(true)
                .addFilters(filterChainProxy)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAnonymous() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/user/account")).andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection());
    }

    @Test
    public void testUserAccessForAccount() throws Exception{
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/user/account")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

What's the easiest way to make the last two tests pass?
@WithMockUser didn't work.

Comment: Tried by annotating your methods with `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('ADMIN')")`

Comment: Sounds like repeating code, as I already authorize them in the security config, and it does work - with actual users, not in tests

Comment: I can't autowire filter chain proxy, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should not add the FilterChainProxy directly. Instead, you should apply `SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()` as indicated by [the reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-setup). An example is included below:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
```

The result of this is:

- the `FilterChainProxy` is added as a `Filter` to `MockMvc` (as you did)
- the `TestSecurityContextHolderPostProcessor` is added

Why is `TestSecurityContextHolderPostProcessor` necessary? The reason is that we need to communicate the current user from the test method to the `MockHttpServletRequest` that is created. This is necessary because Spring Security's `SecurityContextRepositoryFilter` will override any value on `SecurityContextHolder` to be the value found by the current `SecurityContextRepository` (i.e. the `SecurityContext` in `HttpSession`).

**Update**

Remember anything that contains role in the method name automatically prefixes "ROLE_" to the string that was passed in.

Based on your comment, the problem is you need to either update your configuration to use hasRole instead of hasAuthority (since your annotation is using roles):

```
.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/user/**", "/user").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**", "/templates/admin/**", "/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
```

*Alternatively*

You in Spring Security 4.0.2+ you can use:

```
@WithMockUser(authorities="ADMIN")
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I can use with(user("...").roles("ADMIN")) - but a @WithMockUser(roles="ADMIN") call to (admin role protected) /admin/health still gives me a 403, as if the roles parameter was ignored :/

Comment: Can you provide a link to a new question or update your configuration?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. See the udpate

Comment: I am indeed using authorities in my config, but changing `roles` to `authorities` here didn't help - getting a 302 to /login this time. I have a gradle dependency for spring-security-web:4.0.2.RELEASE.

Comment: Please post new question with all the details. You can post link in comments and I'll respond

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818729/spring-withmockuser-ignores-authorities-parameter P.S. you're awesome ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, figured it out.

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/api/user/account")
      .with(user("user")))
      .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

It works now.

Comment: Spring Security allows to specify the actual user of a request [in multiple ways](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-securitycontextholder). You should also be able to annotate the test method with something like `@WithMockUser(roles="ADMIN")` as explained in the referenced documentation

Comment: The thing is - @WithMockUser(roles = "USER") didn't work with the method, contrary to with(user(...)).

Also,
            mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/health").with(user("user").roles("ADMIN"))).andExpect(status().isOk());

doesn't work either. I totally don't get it

Comment: Where is the static user() defined (Eclipse fails totally on including static)

Comment: Hey, it's `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user`, most likely from the `spring-security-test` library.

Comment: `.with(user("user"))` ignores any kind of permission or role based security