# spring boot 2 test ignores ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have a oauth2 resource server with the following rules:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/client/all").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/api/client/create", "/api/client/update", "/api/client/delete/*").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/api/client/*").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
;
```

I can verify that the urls are secured by using postman and sending bearer tokens from different users causes authorization access for users you don't have he right roles. So my code works hen running the application. Now I want to write tests for my resource server. I have noticed something weird going on. No matter what I do spring only using the AffirmativeBased decision manager during testing. I can't get spring to test if users have a certain role. This does happen when running the application however during junit testing spring securty isn't matching the roles. My test class has the following annotation:

```
@WebMvcTest(ClientController.class)
```

which should set spring security. I also inject the mockmvc like this:

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

I have seen people building their own mockmvc instead of injecting it. For example like this:

```
MockMvcBuilders
    .webAppContextSetup(context)
    .apply(springSecurity())
    .build();
```

Which is the right way? And why wont spring security match the roles during testing?

Comment: Does this fit with https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6514 ? Presumably you could @Import the configuration class in the test?

Comment: Unfornately that didn't work. Even with the suggested solution all my urls are returning 401. It's as if security is on however all the rules aren't applied.

Comment: Possibly @AutoConfigureMockMvc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327923/spring-boot-webmvc-tests-not-including-spring-security ?